# How many compact complex 3-folds with $b^1 = b^2=h^{1,2}=0$?

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Are there any compact complex 3-folds with Betti numbers, $b^1 = b^2 = 0 $ and Hodge number, $h^{1,2}=0$?  If yes, then how plentiful are they?

Comment: If you assume furthermore that your manifold $X$ is simply connected and with $H_3(X,\mathbb{Z})$ torsion-free, so that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{2d}$ for $d\geq 0$, then it follows from surgery theory that $X$ is diffeomorphic to the connected sum of $d$ copies of $S^3\times S^3$ (where $d=0$ means diffeomorphic to $S^6$).

Comment: Now $S^3\times S^3$ has for example the Calabi-Eckmann complex structure, but it is known that this has $h^{1,2}=1$. It also has other complex structures constructed by Tsuji, and I don't know the value of $h^{1,2}$ for those.

Comment: On the other hand the connected sum of $d\geq 2$ copies of $S^3\times S^3$ has complex structures with trivial canonical bundle, constructed by Friedman and Lu-Tian. These all have $h^{1,2}=d-1>0$. There are probably other complex structures, but I am not aware of anyone constructing them.

Comment: And finally, if $S^6$ is a complex manifold, it is not clear at all what the value of $h^{1,2}$ would be.

Comment: @YangMills  Thank you for your comments.  They are very helpful!

Comment: @YangMills  Could you refer me to where I can find more information on the Dolbeault cohomology of the complex structures of Friedman and Lu-Tian on connected sums of $S^3 \times S^3$?

Comment: It is stated (without details) in M.Reid's famous paper http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01458074 and also in this paper of Bozhkov http://rendiconti.dmi.units.it/volumi/26/05.pdf

Comment: You should be able to extract a proof from the papers of Bob Friedman http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01458602 and http://jasonpayne.webs.com/Math5339/On%20Threefolds%20with%20Trivial%20Canonical%20Bundle,%20Friedman.pdf

Comment: Friedman first shows that the Hodge-de Rham spectral sequence for these manifolds degenerates at $E_1$, which gives the usual Hodge type decomposition $b_k=\sum_{p+q=k}h^{p,q}$, and since the Betti numbers are easy to compute, he gets the Hodge numbers as well.